# Element Flow Issue, Possibly Squarespace Quirk

Tags: squarespace

I'm at my wits end with this one. I'm trying to design this particular element to rearrange itself on small screens (e.g. mobile devices). On regular/bigger screens the elements are side by side. But on cell phones and such, they flow underneath each other. Instead, the elements just overlap each other and bleed into the page footer, utterly disrespecting the boundaries of their containers. I've tried a number of different solutions (like rotating the display property between inline, inline-block and block and eliminating the float property), but nothing seems to work. And I'm totally ready to blame it all on Squarespace.

Someone please help.

Here's the link: [Arcan: Title Page (Demo)](http://www.worldsofepoch.com/title-2)

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class='book-profile'> <!-- profile -->
  <div class='bprof-frame' style='width: 40%;'> <!-- frame -->
    <div class='bprof-left'> <!-- left container -->
      <img src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56365d8fe4b01da6f9449978/t/5abc0a40352f53d1860e1018/1487723572274/book-cover.jpg?format=500w'>
    </div> <!-- end left container -->
  </div> <!-- end frame -->
  <div class='bprof-frame' style='width: 60%;'> <!-- right frame -->
    <div class='bprof-right'> <!-- right container -->
      <div class='bp-rt-content active'>
        <h2>Available Now</h2>
        <h3>Digital + Paperback</h3>
        <a href='http://www.worldsofepoch.com/store?category=Arcan' class='bp-button' target='_blank'>Purchase</a><br>
        <p class='bp-ava'>
          Also available
        </p><br>
        <img            src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56365d8fe4b01da6f9449978/t/5abc0a40352f53d1860e101a/1522268546298/availability-brands.png?format=750w'>
      </div>
      <div class='bp-rt-content'>
        <h2>
          Reviews
        </h2>
        <!-- <h3>
          &#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;&nbsp;&#9733;
        </h3> -->
        <div class='bp-rev'>
          <ul>
            <li>"The story throws you into an endless ravine of mystery, suspense, action, and duty. I only wish I could fall faster." <span class='rev-auth'>—Danny T., <i>Amazon Customer</i></span></li>
            <li>"...While I'm HUGE on character development, I'm blown away at the world he's created (Terra)." <span class='rev-auth'>—Curiouser Editing</span></li>
            <li>"Brooks brings a refreshing take to the fantasy genre along with a new set of dynamic characters and lore to discover."<span class='rev-auth'>—Angela J. Ford, <i>The Four Worlds</i> Series</span></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='bp-rt-content'>
        <h2>
          The Long Night Comes
        </h2>
        <div class='bp-desc'>
          <span class='dropcaps'>T</span>he sun has begun to set on Terra, giving reign to the unholy Night foretold by the Verses. The <i>Exxarians</i> have returned to reap the destruction sown into the earth several millennia ago. But the object of their ruinous plot has eluded them in the form of a crafty soldier. Kyran, the last of the Arcans and bearer of the <i>Godfall</i>, finds himself on an unlikely journey, uncovering secrets about his primordial lineage. Such secrets, once realized, could mean the downfall of a calculated and genius scheme for the Exxarians. But, while Kyran endeavors to find his way, the Exxarians grow ever closer to the culmination of their apocalyptic design. He is the final piece.
        </div>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- end container -->
    <div class='bprof-nav'>
      <div class='bp-nav-content'>
        <ul>
            <li><a class='bp-nav-link active' onclick='currentSlide(1)'>Buy</a></li>
            <li><a class='bp-nav-link' onclick='currentSlide(2)'>Reviews</a></li>
          <li><a class='bp-nav-link' onclick='currentSlide(0)'>About</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> <!-- end frame -->
</div> <!-- end profile -->
```

Here's the CSS:

```
div.book-profile div{
    //background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
  } 
  .book-profile{
    width: 100%;
    //height: auto;
    //border: blue 2px solid; box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .bprof-frame {
    //width:50%;
    //height: 768px //test
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    //border: purple 2px solid; box-sizing: border-box;
    //background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  }
  .bprof-left{
    //height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    //border: green 2px solid; box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .bprof-left img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .bprof-right{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 90%;
    display: inline-block;
    //display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    //top: 0;
    //background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
    //border: red 2px solid; box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .bp-rt-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -1em;
    //top: 50%;
    //transform: translateY(-50%);
    //background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  }
  .bp-rt-content img{
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1em;
  }
  .bprof-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    //background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.1) !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .bprof-nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    //font-family: 'Dosis';
    //font-size: smaller;
    //font-weight: 500;
    //text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
  .bprof-nav li{
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  .bp-nav-content {
    display: inline-block;
    //line-height: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  .bp-nav-content a,
  .bp-nav-content a:visited{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .bp-nav-content a.active{
    color: black;
    cursor: text;
  }
  .bp-rt-content a,
  .bp-rt-content a:visited{
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin: 10% auto;
    border: black 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    font-family: 'Dosis';
    //font-size: smaller;
  }
  .bp-rt-content a:hover,
  .bp-rt-content a:active{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .bp-rev {
    position: relative;
    //top: -1em;
  }
  .bp-rev ul{
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .bp-rev li{
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    background: linear-gradient(white,white,rgba(255,255,255,0.5));
    margin: 0 auto 1em;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  .rev-auth {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: smaller;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    //line-height: 1em;
  }
  .bp-desc {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .bp-ava {
    color: gray;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    font-size: small;
    //text-transform: uppercase;
    //font-family: 'Dosis';
    line-height: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Here's the Javascript in the head:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var contentwidth = $(window).width();

  function imageresize(){
    //alert('Running imageresize()');
    if ((contentwidth) < 768){
      //alert('Mobile-sized window');
      $('.bprof-frame').css({
        'float':'none',
        'width':'100%'
      });
      $('.saga-box').css({
        'float':'none',
        'width':'100%'
      });
    }
    else {
      //alert('Regular window');
    }
  } // END IMAGERESIZE()

  imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads    

  $(window).on("resize", function(){
    imageresize();
  }); // END ON-RESIZE

 }); // END DOCUMENT READY
```